# Testing a sub-component with a Link: '<Link>s rendered outside of a router context cannot navigate.'

Tags: unit-testing, react-router, enzyme

I have a button component that creates a `react-router` `Link` element. It also allows an `onClick` function to be passed in for additional functionality (e.g. sending a Google Analytics event).

I have included this component in a parent, like so:

```
export default class Page extends Component {
   const doSomething = () => {
    //do a thing to test here
   }

   return (
      <div>
         <Button
            onClickFn{() => doSomething()}
            linkToUrl='/other/page' //this creates a <Link> inside the button
          />
      </div>
   )
}
```

Problem comes when I want to test that `doSomething` is being triggered correctly. I have used Enzyme mount to create the test `Page` component including the button. When I simulate a click I get the following error

```
 '<Link>s rendered outside of a router context cannot navigate.'
```

because the Link in the button has no context. Is there a way of mocking this or preventing the error from showing? Or is there a better way of testing this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your test, you will need to render the component within a `<Router>`. You can take a look at the [tests for the `<Link>` component](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.2/modules/__tests__/Link-test.js#L343) for examples on how to do this.

The basic idea is to create a memory history instance, pass that to the `<Router>`, and then render the `<Link>` inside of a `<Route>` passed to that. It sounds a bit involved, but it is fairly simple.

```js
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history'

it('clicks', () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory()
  const App = () => (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path='/' component={Page} />
    </Router>
  )
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on top of Paul's answer, here's a more detailed example for testing the `onClick` of a `Button` (or its `Link` child to be more precise). The example uses the testing libraries mocha (BDD test runner), chai (BDD assertions), enzyme (React testing utility), and sinon (test doubles).

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';

import MyCustomPage from '/.index';

describe('MyCustomPage', function(){
  it('stores data when clicking the link', function() {
    // Arrange
    const Page = () => (
      <MyCustomPage foo="foo" bar="bar" />
    );

    const container = enzyme.mount(
      <Router history={createMemoryHistory()}>
        <Route path="/" component={Page} />
      </Router>
    );

    // Act
    container.find('#my-link').simulate('click');

    // Assert
    expect(sessionStorage.setItem).to.have.been.calledWith('key', 'value');
  });
});
```